# Best way to make command line utility out of python function or method?

Tags: python, argparse

I write lots of little utility functions which I would like to make available both directly through the command line but also importable as python functions to be used by other utilities. Currently what I do is write my function in a file, and in the same file under `if __name__ == "__main__":` I use argparse to interface with the function on the command line. For example, let's say I have the file `math.py`:

```py
import argparse

def add_or_subtract(a: float, b: float, c: float = 1., add: bool = True) -> float:
    """
    Do some random math

    Parameters
    ----------
    a : float
        A number
    b : float
        Another number
    c : float, optional
        Another number
    add : bool, optional
        Whether to add or subtract c

    Returns
    -------
    answer : float
        The answer
    """
    if add:
        return a+b+c
    else:
        return a+b-c

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("a", type=float, help="a number")
    parser.add_argument("b", type=float, help="another number")
    parser.add_argument("-c", "--c", type=float, help="another number", default=1.)
    parser.add_argument("-a", "--add", action=store_true)
    parser.parse_args()
    print(add_or_subtract(parser.a, parser.b, parser.c, parser.add))
```

Basically I have the feeling that I am doing a lot of duplication defining arguments, their acceptable types, and their explanations. If I change some arguments on the function I have to remember to update it in three places. I'm wondering if there is an easier way.

I've been playing a bit with `inspect` to add CLI arguments based on the arguments in the function, but I want something a bit "smarter" that knows the difference between mandatory and optional arguments, acceptable types, boolean flags etc. It would be even greater if the docstrings could also be parsed for the help. The ideal scenario would be a kind of decorator that "command-lineifies" the function.

Does something like I'm describing exist? Or are there better ways of doing what I want.

Comment: What you are doing is normal `argparse`.  There are other parsers (some built on `argparse`) that can create a parser from the specifications of a function.  One that I've used in the past, but not recently, is `plac`

Comment: Look at the https://pypi.org/project/plac/ code to see how work you are talking about!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try implementing commands as classes and later just inherit those?

Something like this might work:

```
class CommandArgument:

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def add_to_parser(self, parser: argparse.ArgumentParser):
        parser.add_argument(*self.args, **self.kwargs)


class BaseAddOrSubCommand:

    a = CommandArgument('a', type=float, help='a number')
    b = CommandArgument('b', type=float, help='another number')
    c = CommandArgument('b', type=float, help='another number')
    args = [a, b, c]

    def __init__(self):
        self.parser = argparse.ArgumentParser
        for arg in self.args:
            arg.add_to_parser(self.parser)
        self.parser.parse_args()

    def execute(self):
        if self.parser.add:
            return self.parser.a + self.parser.b + self.parser.c
        else:
            return self.parser.a + self.parser.b - self.parser.c


class MultiplySumOrSubCommand(BaseAddOrSubCommand):

    mult = CommandArgument('mult', type=float, help='multiply result with me')
    args = BaseAddOrSubCommand.args + [mult]

    def execute(self):
        return super().execute() * self.parser.mult


if __name__ == '__main__':
    command = MultiplySumOrSubCommand()
    print(command.execute())
```